# Website not displaying correctly on mobile devices, tested on Samsung A30 & Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: bootstrap-4

I hope this is quite an easy one for you to fix, but the website I've mentioned below doesn't seem to be displaying correctly on mobile devices as mentioned in the subject.

The website in question is [www.resthaven.co.za](https://www.resthaven.co.za/).

Please see the screenshots attached using a Samsung Galaxy S2 below:

[image]
[image]

I'm using bootstrap-4.3.1 for this website, & to be honest I'm a bit stumped as to if it could be bootstrap or my own css styling causing this issue :-|, so if you need to do more troubleshooting please view the websites source ;-).

Cheers,
Tim K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add width: 100%; in your image style

Comment: <img alt="Resthaven Guesthouse" class="main-img" src="https://www.resthaven.co.za/rhgh/img/Resthaven Guesthouse by Day.jpg" style="
    width: 100%;
">

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry I might be incorrect, width: 100% might be working after all :-|.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your site using my laptop and added the Bootstrap class `img-fluid` to the top image tag and then added the `p-1` class to the button so it would fit on the display and it seems to work (at least in emulation mode on a laptop).

```
<img class="main-img img-fluid" alt="Resthaven Guesthouse" src="https://www.resthaven.co.za/rhgh/img/Resthaven Guesthouse by Day.jpg" width="420" height="280">

<button class="navbar-toggler p-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

Plus, you can eliminate the `p` tag around the img.

Comment: thanks very much, however it seems like <img ... style=" width: 100%; "> did the trick after all ;-).  Thanks again for your answer though, I appreciate it.